# Count if a word occurs in each row of a 4 million observation data set

Tags: r, text, text-analysis

I am using R and writing a script that counts if one of ~2000 words occurs in each row of a 4 million observation data file. The data set with observations (df) contains two columns, one with text (df$lead_paragraph), and one with a date (df$date).

Using the following, I can count if any of the words in a list (p) occur in each row of the lead_paragraph column of the df file, and output the answer as a new column.

```
   df$pcount<-((rowSums(sapply(p, grepl, df$lead_paragraph, 
   ignore.case=TRUE) == TRUE, na.rm=T) > 0) * 1)
```

However, if I include too many words in the list p, running the code crashes R.

My alternate strategy is to simply break this into pieces, but I was wondering if there is a better, more elegant coding solution to use here. My inclination is to use a for loop, but everything I am reading suggests this is not preferred in R. I am pretty new to R and not a very good coder, so my apologies if this is not clear.

```
    df$pcount1<-((rowSums(sapply(p[1:100], grepl, df$lead_paragraph, 
    ignore.case=TRUE) == TRUE, na.rm=T) > 0) * 1)
    df$pcount2<-((rowSums(sapply(p[101:200], grepl, df$lead_paragraph, 
    ignore.case=TRUE) == TRUE, na.rm=T) > 0) * 1) 
    ...
    df$pcount22<-((rowSums(sapply(p[2101:2200], grepl, df$lead_paragraph, 
    ignore.case=TRUE) == TRUE, na.rm=T) > 0) * 1)
```

Comment: A couple of things/tips, but definitely not a solution (yet). First, the bigger the data, the better off you'd be moving away from base R (maybe use `data.tables`?). Second, I would use the `any` function, in which case you can skip the `rowSums` part, as well as the inequality and the multiplication. Third, do you know if the words would appear at random or if there's some pattern, i.e. at the beginning or end? If yes, that would greatly simplify things. Last, try parsing the text, to get rid of unnecessary memory usage.

Comment: Is the goal to count the occurrences of any strings in `p` that exist in each row?
such that: 
`for each row of data frame x, count N occurrences of any string in P and total into a new row`?

Comment: @CarlBoneri -- Yes, ultimately, I simply need to know if any of the strings in p occur in a given row of the data (binary, true/false), but a count would be sufficient.

Comment: oh if it's `any` then disregard my below approach and opt for any (stri_detect_regex)

Comment: @YannisVassiliadis Thank you for the tips on <code> any</code>  and <code> data.tables </code> . There is no discernible pattern to where the words will occur. By parsing, what exactly do you mean? I can imagine removing common words that are unnecessary to the analysis from the data in <code> df_leadparagraph.</code>

Comment: Np @chydock. By parsing, I meant remove stop words ("a", "and" etc - assuming they're not in 'p') and stem the words (e.g. read, reads, reading, reader all have the same stem, so you can just keep the stem). This will make the entire process less memory intensive. But only do that, assuming the different words are not part of 'p'. Btw only use 'any' if you want t'a 0-1 coding, not if you want the full count.

Comment: Also, you can check out the quanteda package, but I'm sure there are many other packages too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't complete this... but this should point you in the right direction. It's faster using the `data.table` package, but hopefully this gives you an idea of the process.

I recreated your dataset using random dates and strings which were
extracted from http://www.norvig.com/big.txt into a data.frame
named `nrv_df`

```
library(stringi)

> head(nrv_df)
                                                             lead_para       date
1     The Project Gutenberg EBook of The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes 2018-11-16
2                                            by Sir Arthur Conan Doyle 2019-06-05
3                           15 in our series by Sir Arthur Conan Doyle 2017-08-08
4  Copyright laws are changing all over the world Be sure to check the 2014-12-17
5 copyright laws for your country before downloading or redistributing 2016-09-13
6                            this or any other Project Gutenberg eBook 2015-06-15

> dim(nrv_df)
[1] 103598      2

I then randomly sampled words from the entire body to get 2000 unique words
> length(p)
[1] 2000
> head(p)
[1] "The"        "Project"    "Gutenberg"  "EBook"      "of"         "Adventures"
> tail(p)
[1] "accomplice" "engaged"    "guessed"    "row"        "moist"      "red"
```

Then, to leverage the `stringi` package and using a regex to match complete
cases of the words, I joined each of the strings in vector `p`, and 
collapsed then with a `|`, so that we are looking for any words with a `word-boundary` 
before or after:

```
> p_join2 <- stri_join(sprintf("\\b%s\\b", p), collapse = "|")
> p_join2

[1] "\\bThe\\b|\\bProject\\b|\\bGutenberg\\b|\\bEBook\\b|\\bof\\b|\\bAdventures\\b|\\bSherlock\\b|\\bHolmes\\b|\\bby\\b|\\bSir\\b|\\bArthur\\b|\\bConan\\b|\\bDoyle\\b|\\b15\\b|\\bin\\b|\\bour\\b|\\bseries\\b|\\bCopyright\\b|\\blaws\\b|\\bare\\b|\\bchanging\\b|\\ball\\b|\\bover\\b|\\bthe\\b|\\bworld\\b|\\bBe\\b|\\bsure\\b|\\bto\\b|\\bcheck\\b|\\bcopyright\\b|\\bfor\\b|\\byour\\b|\\bcountry\\b|..."
```

And then simply count the words and you could do `nrv_df$counts <-` to add this as a column...

```
> stri_count_regex(nrv_df$lead_para[25000:26000], p_join2, stri_opts_regex(case_insensitive = TRUE))
[1] 12 11  8 13  7  7  6  7  6  8 12  1  6  7  8  3  5  3  5  5  5  4  7  5  5  5  5  5 10  2  8 13  5  8  9  7  6  5  7  5  9  8  7  5  7  8  5  6  0  8  6
[52]  3  4  0 10  7  9  8  4  6  8  8  7  6  6  6  0  3  5  4  7  6  5  7 10  8 10 10 11
```

## EDIT:

Since it's of no consequence to find the number of matches...
First a function to do the work to each paragraph and detect if any of the stirngs in `p2` exist in the body of `lead_paragraph`

```
f <- function(i, j){
     if(any(stri_detect_fixed(i, j, omit_no_match = TRUE))){
         1
     }else {
         0
     }
 }
```

Now... using the `parallel` library on linux. And only testing 1000 rows since it's an example gives us:

```
library(parallel)
library(stringi)
> rst <- mcmapply(function(x){
    f(i = x, j = p2)
}, vdf2$lead_paragraph[1:1000], 
mc.cores = detectCores() - 2,
USE.NAMES = FALSE)
> rst
   [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  [70] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [139] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
 [208] 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [277] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [346] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
 [415] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [484] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [553] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [622] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [691] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [760] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [829] 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [898] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [967] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Both solutions worked great, thank you. As desired, they ran without inducing a crash when I included the entire dataset (4mil rows), and did not require segmenting the analysis.

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
library(corpus)

# simulate the problem as in @carl-boneri's answer
lead_para <- readLines("http://www.norvig.com/big.txt")

# get a random sample of 2000 word types
types <- text_types(lead_para, collapse = TRUE)
p <- sample(types, 2000)

# find whether each entry has at least one of the terms in `p`
ix <- text_detect(lead_para, p)
```

Even only using a single core, it's over 20 times faster than the previous solution:

```
system.time(ix <- text_detect(lead_para, p))
##  user  system elapsed 
## 0.231   0.008   0.240

system.time(rst <- mcmapply(function(x) f(i = x, j = p_join2),
                            lead_para, mc.cores = detectCores() - 2,
                            USE.NAMES = FALSE))
##   user  system elapsed 
## 11.604   0.240   5.805
```